# How to delete a Folder and all its shortcuts using shell scripting

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript

I have dragged and dropped a folder to "Start Menu", how to delete folder and all its references from "Start Menu", "Task Bar", "Desktop"

I am am able unpin program shortcuts using WSScript.exe (got Pin.vbs script from here https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/549865-vbs-script-for-pin-and-unpinning-taskbar-icons)
However i am unable to Unpin Folder that is Dragged and dropped to Start menu.

Not found below folders or in entire registry or entire file system. Not sure how this is persisted in Start menu.

`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
or

`C:\Users\USERID\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\StartMenu`

Comment: Which version of Windows are using?

Comment: Windows 7 or windows 8

Comment: The script is only going to work pinning applications not files or folders. For Windows 7, they are encoded binary values living in the keys in this registry location:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartPage2`

Comment: Thanks BenH, you are correct my folder is in binary format. Is there anyway we can edit Binary Registry value and remove the folder references from Start Menu?

Comment: It's not documented at all. I've seen a Win10 script where you add the folder to find the binary signature that you want to remove then delete that substring out of the registry. But it's all undocumented because [Microsoft doesn't want you playing around with it.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030903-00/?p=42673/)